# How to share a connection between two interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, firewalld

Okay so either I am dummer then I look or there is a real problem here.

Fedora 23
Interface 1: enp9s0 192.168.1.137 255.255.255.0 Wired (Internet connection)
Interface 2: wlp0s20u14 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.128 Wireless (no internet connection)

Here is what I am trying to do:

Create a wireless hotspot on interface 2 and then have anyone who connects to have access to the internet via interface 1 which is connected to the internet.

The list of things that I have tried thus far is hilariously long.
Tried switching from firewalld to iptables, follow a good amount of guides on the net but to no avail.

Can anyone help me share the connection from interface 1 to interface 2 and all the devices connected to the interface 2?

Creating a hotspot seams to work and I get the dhcpd server to run on interface 2 and the devices get the ip addresses but they do not have internet access.

Could someone please help me out? I ran out of options here. If possible at all I would like to stick with firewalld due to some virtual machines that are running but if not I ll gladly take what I can get and iptables will do just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that should work for some of you. Just 6 lines to share internet with the WiFi network you have created.

**To simply bridge two interfaces**, install & use the package `bridge-utils`

```
apt-get install bridge-utils
```

then you can use `brctl`

```
brctl addbr foo
brctl addif enp9s0
brctl addif wlp0s20u14
```

where

> foo : The name to give for this new bridged interface
>
> anp9s0 : interface you have internet access
>
> wlp0s20u14 : interface running your WiFi HotSpot

Then bring your interfaces up that way

```
ifconfig enp9s0 0.0.0.0 up
ifconfig wlp0s20u14 0.0.0.0 up
ifconfig foo up
```

Down part is that YOU will not have internet access.
I'm using that method on VM's

**To create your own WiFi HotSpot**, you can use `airbase-ng`.

```
airbase-ng --esssid MyWiFi wlan0
```

where

> --essid : Parameters set to define your own essid. (default is 'default')
> wlan0 : The wireless interface to use

This will then create the WiFi HotSpot on a new interface (at0).
You can then bridge that interface like I said.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the machine working as a hotspot and dhcpd working, you just need to make work as a router - my recommandation is to try finding a guide to setup the version of Fedora you use as a router.

It basically comes down to:

1. enable ip forwarding
2. set up routing
3. set up masquerading
4. allow the traffic in whatever firewall you use.

I've never used Fedora or firewalld, so I don't know what the good way of doing it in your setup is, but enabling IP forwarding is just `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, routing is probably correct if internet access works on the fedora box, masquerading is something like `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s wlp0s20u14 -j MASQUERADE`, for firewalling you want to make sure the kinds of traffic you want/don't want are allowed/blocked in the `FORWARD` chain of netfilter (the framework in the kernel that does the work, `iptables` is just a frontend, I can't imagine firewalld being anything else).

Comment: Can you help me out with setting up routing, this is the current output of route -n Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.50    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp9s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp9s0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 at0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

Comment: at0 is the wireless interface in this case I am just using airbase-ng to test the wireless hotspot out